# Clean a log file using sed Linux command

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need to replace a string from a file by deleting all the lines which have got that occurrence, and replace all that with the first occurrence. I have got something like this:

```
errorMain="ERROR this is the error"
var1=$( grep "$errorMain" log_verification.log )
errorCount1=$(grep -c "$errorMain" log_verification.log)

countErrors() {
if [ $errorCount1 -gt 10 ] ; 
then
replaceFirstOccurrence
fi
}

replaceFirstOccurrence() {
firstOccurrence=$(grep -m 1 "$errorMain" log_verification.log)
echo "the error $firstOccurrence is repeated $errorCount1 times"
sed -i 's/$errorMain/$firstOccurrence/g' log_verification.log > log_without_redundant.log
}

countErrors
```

I need to replace all the occurrences with something like:

The following error is repeated X times:
ERROR this is the error

And output that to a new file.

Any ideas?

## EDIT

The new file needs to be equal to the original one (same content) the only lines which are replaced are the ones with that occurrence.

Comment: consider editing your question to include a small sample file including 2 lines of data to be processed, 1 line of data that should be excluded. Show your expected output. Then show your attempt to code a solution. Show any error messages (exact copy/paste). Show failed output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I find this line wrong:

```
sed -i 's/$errorMain/$firstOccurrence/g' log_verification.log > log_without_redundant.log
```

The right approach should be:

```
sed -i "s/.*$errorMain.*/$firstOccurrence/" log_verification.log > log_without_redundant.log
```

The single quotation marks on sh scripts are used for literal, not variable substitution. Double quotation marks will expand your variables. And also for complete substitution you need to add the `.*` before and after, to match any other characters on the line. Also the `/g` means that you try more than once on a line, it should be removed.